# Node Elasticsearch bulk index fails silently

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Using Nodejs client to work with Elasticsearch:

- Elasticsearch 6.6
- Node Elasticsearch client 15.4.1

I am trying to bulk index a bunch of entries with this function:

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const configuration = require('./configuration').elasticConfig;
const elastic = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: `${configuration.host}:${configuration.port}`
});

const elasticStore = async (inputArray) => {
    try {
        const insert = await elastic.bulk({body: inputArray});
        console.log(insert)
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('failed to insert events into elastic search', {e});
    }
};
```

I am running elasticStore on the following inputArray:

```
[
  {
    "index": {
      "_index": "test-2019.02.19"
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-02-19T02:34:43.526Z",
    "data": {
      "something": "something"
    }
  },
  {
    "index": {
      "_index": "test-2019.02.19"
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-02-19T02:34:43.526Z",
    "data": {
      "something": "something"
    }
  }
]
```

The function fails on insert, but it fails silently-it does not throw an error or anything like this.

I am looking at the documentation, and their example is like this:

```
client.bulk({
  body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: 'myindex', _type: 'mytype', _id: 1 } },
     // the document to index
    { title: 'foo' }
  ]
})
```

Even when I run the example, like this:

```
const insert = await elastic.bulk({body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: 'sb-app-events-test', _type: 'mytype', _id: 1 } },
    // the document to index
    { title: 'foo' }
]});
```

it also fails silently.

I thought that perhaps the issue is the array of JSON objects I'm using for the body (though the official documentation says this should work fine,) and tried converting it to JSONLines, creating a string of stringified objects separated by newline characters, but it fails the same way:

```
    let parsedInput ='';
    inputArray.forEach(obj => parsedInput += JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n')
    const insert = await elastic.bulk({body: parsedInput});
```

this produced the following string:

```
"{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"myindex\",\"_type\":\"mytype\"}}\n{\"title\":\"foo\"}\n{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"myindex\",\"_type\":\"mytype\"}}\n{\"title\":\"foo\"}\n"
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Duy's answer below fixed my issue-it needed a type in both the top level and each insert object. Webstorm debugging with breakpoints does not work here for some reason, I had to console.log().

Comment: What elasticsearch version? Can you paste a sample of bulk body json? There should be line separate between the action, document, and at the end as well. Also there must be a response, you might have ignore it in code. Maybe debug with breakpoint to see the response

Comment: Version 15.4.1. The bulk body json example is above. What do you mean that a line should separate the action, document and the end? In the example code on the ES site, it says  "the request body, as either an array of objects or new-line delimited JSON objects".

Comment: I am running it in the debugger. The response should be stores as the insert variable-since I'm not passing a callback at the end, the ES client should run this as a Promise, and I'm using it with async/await.

Comment: I believe @ziv is asking what is the version of the Elasticsearch cluster where you try to index the data.

Comment: I'm using ES 6.6.

Comment: The above body you pasted is from code perspective, not elastic rest request body, the rest request body should be multiple lines, even number of lines, each line is a json, but all the body all together is not a json. The lines are pairs. First line is the operation, the second is the doc. It can't spread the doc to multiple lines. And, in the end of the pairs there should be a new line as well.

Comment: Again-not sure I understand. Does this mean that I can't just use an array of valid JSON objects, every odd one like this `{ index:  { _index: 'sb-app-events-test', _type: 'mytype', _id: 1 } }` and every even one like this `{ title: 'foo' }`?

Comment: I have no idea about log, but seem `logger ` is not defined, is it?

Comment: Logger is defined elsewhere in the code, and works fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the node client, but if there's no response it is probably the client code not sending the request as all, or that it dropped the response. ES will always return an error response with the failure reason. Once you'll get to that response you can understand why it failed

Comment: @BorisK did you try with a callback as the second argument?
```client.bulk({
  body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: 'myindex', _type: 'mytype', _id: 1 } },
  ]
}, function (err, resp) {
  // ...
});```

Comment: Yes, I have. It never runs the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked your code and see, you forget to pass `type` to `bulk` function

```
# Modify const insert = await elastic.bulk({body: inputArray});
# Become
const insert = await elastic.bulk({ body: inputArray, type: 'mytype'});
```

Tested with https://gist.github.com/duynguyenhoang/b05c1c6342f639e440422256c68fd040 and it works well

*Note*: Nodejs v8.11.1

Comment: Not only that, but the official docs say to put the type inside each insert object, not at the top level of the bulk request:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk

Comment: It accepts `type ` as well https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/v15.4.1/src/lib/apis/6_6.js#L24, Default document type for items which don't provide one

Comment: FYI, I have tried with my node and ES and it works well. My script is in https://gist.github.com/duynguyenhoang/b05c1c6342f639e440422256c68fd040

Comment: I'm doing the same thing: `const insert = await elastic.bulk({body: inputArray, type: 'test_es'});` and it is still dying silently.

Comment: This now works. Adding the body in both the top level and each object made the difference. Also, there was weirdness with the Webstorm debugger-I had to console.log() and run normally instead of with breakpoints to see what was going on.